# get_absolute_url not adding information to HTML file

Tags: python, html, django

I'm doing the effectivedjango tutorial, but I ran into a problem: While using `get_absolute_url`, it does not add the id to the HTML code (see the bottom of [this](http://effectivedjango.com/tutorial/additional-views.html) page). I have tried to find my error and looked up the passage in the Django docs. According to that, I seem to do fine. I tried to understand the other questions about `get_absolute_url` on the forum as well but if I understood, it did not turn out to solve the issue. I also looked up the information about `kwargs` to check my syntax, but could not find a mistake.

This is all the related code (as it seems):

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join([
            self.first_name,
            self.last_name,
        ])

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('contacts-view', kwargs={'pk': self.id})
```

`urls.py`:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', contacts.views.ContactView.as_view(), name='contacts-view',),
```

`views.py`:

```
class ContactView(DetailView):
    model = Contact
    template_name = 'contact.html'
```

`contact_list.html`:

```
<ul>
  {% for contact in object_list %}
    <li class="contact">
      <a href="{{ contact.get_absolute_url }}"> {{contact}}</a>
      (<a href="{% url 'contacts-edit' pk=contact.id %}" >edit</a>)
      (<a href="{% url 'contacts-delete' pk=contact.id %}">delete</a>)<br>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Now, I am expecting a `1` after the first `href` in the generated source of the `contact_list` HTML file, which is missing (just a section):

```
<li class="contact">
    <a href=""> Maaike van der Vlies</a>
    (<a href="/edit/1/" >edit</a>)
    (<a href="/delete/1/">delete</a>)<br>
</li>
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I not expect the `1` or is there some other thing I am missing?

Comment: does your contacts view work... can you go to `/1/` in a browser and see that contact?

Comment: yes it does. /1/ works when typed in the browser

Comment: what do you see if you run `reverse('contacts-view', kwargs={'pk': 1})` in `python manage.py shell` ?

Comment: I assume your `get_absolute_url` is _inside_ the `Contact` model definition and not just loose in models.py?

Comment: after running the command, I get 'NameError: name 'reverse' is not defined'

Comment: and I edited the post to show my full models.py

Comment: if that's all the code you have in `models.py` you might be missing the import `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse` which could cause an ImportError and cause the tag to fail silently. Try it in a shell.

Comment: Just saw @Anentropic's comment about the shell and your answer, you are missing the import it seems and the tag is failing, Anentropic should post the solution

Comment: i don't know exact solution,

but one's time you also try this

<a href="/contacts/{{contact.id}}"> {{contact}}</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a fair solution to why your reverse fails, I don't see it either, but you can build your template without that method.
So change `<a href="{{ contact.get_absolute_url }}">{{contact}}</a>` into `<a href="{% url 'contacts-view' pk=contact.id %}">{{contact}}</a>`

Comment: I know this solution, but shouldn't get_absolute_url work as well? It is described in the python docs as the preferred method and I wanted to learn to understand the method.

Comment: As the other comments/answers say, the method probally fails, which is hidden by your template. Add `TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True` to your Django settings to see the error. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#template-debug

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that setting was on though did not show a thing. The mistake is somewhere in the python code

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are maybe missing the import for the `reverse` function. i.e. you need this at the top of your models.py:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
```

If that's missing it would mean that when Django tries to get a value from `get_absolute_url` an error is raised. By default Django will ignore errors that occur during the template rendering (there is a [`TEMPLATE_DEBUG` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#template-debug) which controls this) which would be why you you just get an empty string in your html for `{{ contact.get_absolute_url }}`.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. The import doesn't change a thing though. After changing model.py, a retry in a new browser and executed in the shell, I get 'NameError: name 'reverse' is not defined'

Comment: if you get `NameError: name 'reverse' is not defined` in the shell it's because you didn't import the `reverse` function... this is elementary Python

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I changed the file as to import the reverse function but it doesn't change a thing. Any other ideas? Otherwise I guess I need to learn some more python/djange to find out what I'm doing wrong. I'll use another tutorial to increase my knowledge.